# user.is_authenticated works in html but not views

Tags: django, authentication, django-authentication

I just learned about the django.contrib.auth built-in package and am trying to implement user authentication for my blog application! Doing user.is_authenticated in my html works:

```
<div class="footer">
    <div class='sub-footer'>
       <ul style="list-style:none;">
            <li>-<a href="{% url 'login' %}">Admin, Login Here!</a></li>
            <li>- <a href="https://www.flaticon.com">Pencil Icon made by </a><a href="https://www.flaticon.com/authors/becris">Becris </a><a href="https://www.flaticon.com">from www.flaticon.com</a>
            <li>- <a href="https://www.flaticon.com">Heart Icon made by </a><a href="https://www.flaticon.com/authors/gregor-cresnar">Gregor Cresnar </a><a href="https://www.flaticon.com">from www.flaticon.com</a>

       </ul>
    </div>
    
</div>

{% if user.is_authenticated %}
 yo whats good authenticated user
{% endif %}
```

But, when I try this in my views:

```
if user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'admin.html', context)
return render(request, 'registration.html')
```

I get this error:

```
NameError at /admin-dash/
name 'user' is not defined
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin-dash/
Django Version: 3.1.2
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value:    
name 'user' is not defined
Exception Location: C:\Users\benja\Desktop\mysite\mysite\blog\views.py, line 137, in admin_view
Python Executable:  C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\envs\mysite\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.5
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\benja\\Desktop\\mysite\\mysite',
 'C:\\Users\\benja\\anaconda3\\envs\\mysite\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\benja\\anaconda3\\envs\\mysite\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\benja\\anaconda3\\envs\\mysite\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\benja\\anaconda3\\envs\\mysite',
 'C:\\Users\\benja\\anaconda3\\envs\\mysite\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 10 Jan 2021 00:03:09 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\envs\mysite\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py, line 47, in inner
                response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\envs\mysite\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py, line 179, in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\benja\Desktop\mysite\mysite\blog\views.py, line 137, in admin_view
    if user.is_authenticated: …
▶ Local vars
```

It makes sense, but I was wondering how I could define user in my view to work as it does in HTML.

Thanks y'all!

Answer (score 4):

The user variable is not defined in a view, only `request` is. In the template, the [**`auth`** context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth) in fact adds the `user` to the context, without that context processor, the `user` would not be a variable in the Django templates.

You thus access the user from the `request` object:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    return render(request, 'admin.html', context)
return render(request, 'registration.html')
```